# Performing a query from table and based on result perform another query?

Tags: mysql, node.js

im trying to query an ad from table named ads, using id of the ad i want, and based on that result, i use the ad_userposterid which is the id of the user who posted that ad, and use that ad_userposterid, to query the user row, snd get all his info from table members.
why doing this?

first i need to get the information of the ad 
second i need the information of the user who posted that ad.

when a user post a ad to ads table, the user id get associated to the ad under column name ad_userposterid.
my request:

is it possible to get the two rows data in just one query?.

i searched for example like this but i cant find answer where result is 2 rows from 2 different tables.

i know i can use promises in node.js and make 2 queries but, i want to know if no need for that, if possible get the same result with one query.
thanks.

table 2 name: ads

---

```
| id |    ad_userposterid   |   ad_title           |   ad_price         |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |             2        |   Galaxy s9 for sell |     255            |
| 2  |             1        | iphone for for sell  |       200          |
```

table 1 name: members

```
-------------------------------------------------
| id |      user            |   phone              | 
-------------------------------------------------
| 1  | rida                 | 7277779999           |
| 2  | david                | 7278882222           |
```

Comment: update your question and add  the expected  result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems you need  join

```
select  a.id, a.ad_userposterid, m.user, m.phone 
from  ads a
inner join members m  on a.ad_userposterid = m.id
```